# NetSuite : TypeError record.createCurrentLineItemSubrecord is not a function?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, clientscript

I'm getting

> "TypeError _invadjtransRecord.createiewCurrentLineItemSubrecord is not a function"

**When trying the below code:**

```
var _invadjtransRecord = nlapiCreateRecord('inventoryadjustment');

_invadjtransRecord.setFieldValue('subsidiary', _subsidiary);
_invadjtransRecord.setFieldValue('account', _itemAccount);
_invadjtransRecord.setFieldValue('trandate',dateVal);
_invadjtransRecord.selectNewLineItem('inventory');
_invadjtransRecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventory', 'item', _item);
_invadjtransRecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventory', 'location', _location);
_invadjtransRecord.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventory', 'adjustqtyby', _adjQuantity);
var inventoryDetail = _invadjtransRecord.createCurrentLineItemSubrecord('inventory','inventorydetail');
inventoryDetail.selectNewLineItem('inventoryassignment');
inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'expirationdate', _expDate);
inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'inventorystatus', 1);
inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'issueinventorynumber', _invNo);
inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'quantity', _adjQuantity);
inventoryDetail.commitLineItem('inventoryassignment');
inventoryDetail.commit();
```

Comment: Obviously, _invadjtransRecord.createiewCurrentLineItemSubrecord is not a function but you use it like it is one. There may be typos in function name, for example.

Answer (score 3):

To use the `*Current*` version of the sublist APIs, the `Record` object needs to be in Dynamic mode. See the parameters of `nlapiCreateRecord` for how to specify Standard or Dynamic modes.

Comment: Thanks Erictgrubaugh for your replay, But i tried this code before and i got the same error 
'var _invadjtransRecord = nlapiCreateRecord('inventoryadjustment', { recordmode: 'dynamic' }); '

Answer (score 0):

Is there a missing `.commit()` for the `inventory` lineitems you added?

Comment: The error occurred before `inventoryDetail.commit();` line
that was in 
`var inventoryDetail = _invadjtransRecord.createCurrentLineItemSubrecord('inventory','inventorydetail');`

Answer (score 0):

I would thank you eng **ericgrubaugh** for your help
i searched for Dynamic and Standard modes record and it helped me.
the problem happened when using this code in client side but it should be in server side
with change

```
var _invadjtransRecord = nlapiCreateRecord('inventoryadjustment');
to 
var inventoryDetail = _invadjtransRecord.createCurrentLineItemSubrecord('inventory', 'inventorydetail');
```

references 
[SuiteScript Developer & Reference Guide pdf](https://system.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=5732122&c=NLCORP&h=5fca4bf5dd825a28ab41&_xt=.pdf)
[Suite Answers](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/30601/kw/SuiteScript%201.0%20%E2%80%93%20Standard%20and%20Dynamic%20Modes)

Thanks a lot